# How do the aliens in the "Darkest Hour" get to the Earth?

Tags: alien-invasion

In the movie, [The Darkest Hour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Darkest_Hour_%28film%29), the aliens' arrival is heralded by a total loss of power, a wicked aurora and the usual proceeding chaos.  How did they get to the Earth in the first place?  (and more to the point, where did they come from?)

Answer (score 2):

The alien presence in the Darkest Hour appears more like a migration and less like an invasion. As viewers we are never given any motivation, technology, or indication the creatures are intelligent, self-aware or have any goals beyond absorbing as much energy as possible while they are on Earth.

Their behavior was more like a locusts plague than an alien armada. We cannot rule this out of course, since we didn't get any other information, we are forced to use what they do as an indicator of their intention.

As to their arrival:

- They appear to rain down across the city (and presumably across the planet) and are only visible because of their charged state as they enter the atmosphere. As soon as they lose that energy, they became invisible.

[image]

- Once they arrive, there does not appear to be a strategic order to their movement, it only appears that way because of the uniformity of their arrival and the nature of their energy-related abilities.
- It could appear as a coordinated attack to humans watching it because their abilities caused a citywide loss of power which would be the same strategy an intelligent alien attacker might use to cause disorder and prevent effective communications on Earth.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article on ScriptShadow](http://scriptshadow.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/darkest-hour.html), the "spooks" were originally intended to have arrived in meteors, crashing into Earth and then emerging. No specific indication is given as to why this was later amended to them arriving from space naked, nor how they got into the meteors in the first place.

That being said, the trailer was very clear that it was a deliberate invasion, not just non-sentient creatures moving around space grazing.

> Phase one: Seize the planet
>
> Phase two: Devour all energy
>
> Phase three: Destroy all life